# Difference between splice and remove in winjs listView to remove an item

Tags: windows-8, winjs, windows-8.1

Removing an item from a listView in winjs, what is the difference between those 2 methods?

**Method 1**

```
var _dataSource = myList.itemDataSource;
//Start the sequence of edits
_dataSource.beginEdits();

//remove the firstitem
_dataSource.remove(_dataSource.itemFromIndex(0)._value.key);

//Ends the batch of edits
_dataSource.endEdits();
```

**Method 2**

```
myList.itemDataSource.list.splice(0, 1); //remove the first in the list
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're essentially identical, because Method 1's remove method is actually implemented using Method 2. Set a breakpoint on Method 1's remove call, and then looked at the method implementation in Visual Studio:

```
function remove(key) {
    var index = this._list.indexOfKey(key);
    if (index === -1) {
        return errors.noLongerMeaningful;
    }
    this._list.splice(index, 1);
    return;
}
```

Where _list is what you get from itemDataSource.list.

The difference really lies in the fact that Method 1 has beginEdits and endEdits, so you'd want to use that variant if you were modifying more than one item at a time. That will improve performance.